# Can you target an element with CSS only if 2 classes are present?

Tags: css, css-selectors

As you probably already know, you may have multiple classes on elements separated by a space.

#### Example

```html
<div class="content main"></div>
```

And with CSS you can target that `div` with either `.content` or `.main`. Is there a way to target it if *and only if* both classes are present?

#### Example

```html
<div class="content main">I want this div</div>
<div class="content">I don't care about this one</div>
<div class="main">I don't want this</div>
```

Which CSS selector would I use to get the first `div` only (assume I can't use `.content:first-child` or similar)?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Yes, just concatenate them: `.content.main`. See [CSS class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html).

But note that the Internet Explorer up to version 6 doesn’t support multiple class selectors and just honors the last class name.

Comment: As long as that's 'up to' and not 'inclusive of' IE6 :)

Comment: No, IE6 doesn't correctly understand chained CSS selectors. That rule will apply to *all* elements with class="main" regardless of whether they are class="content" too

Comment: An illustration for IE6 vs other browsers for anyone who cares: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes

Answer (score 14):

Just for the sake of it (I don't really recommend you do this), there *is* another way to do it:

```
.content[class~="main"] {}
```

Or:

```
.main[class~="content"] {}
```

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

> E[foo~="warning"] Matches any E element whose "foo" attribute value is
>   a list of **space-separated values**, one of which is exactly equal to
>   "warning"

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eXrSg/

#### Why this is actually useful (for IE6 at least):

Since IE6 does not support multiple classes, we can't use `.content.main`, **but** there are some javascript libraries like [IE-7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) that enable the attribute selector, but still seem to fail when it comes to multiple classes. I have tested this workaround in IE6 with javascript enabling the attribute selector, and it is ugly, but it works.

I have yet to find a script that makes IE6 support multiple class selectors but have found many that enable attribute selectors. If someone knows of one *that works*, please give me a shout in the comments so I can be rid of this workaround.