# CSS Selector that applies to elements with two classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to select an element with CSS based on the value of the class attribute being set to two specific classes. For example, let's say I have 3 divs:

```html
<div class="foo">Hello Foo</div>
<div class="foo bar">Hello World</div>
<div class="bar">Hello Bar</div>
```

What CSS could I write to select ONLY the second element in the list, based on the fact that it is a member of both the foo AND bar classes?

Answer (score 989, accepted):

Chain both class selectors (without a space in between):

```css
.foo.bar {
  /* Styles for element(s) with foo AND bar classes */
}
```

---

If you still have to deal with ancient browsers like Internet Explorer 6, be aware that it doesn't read chained class selectors correctly: it'll only read the **last** class selector (`.bar` in this case) instead, regardless of what other classes you list.

To illustrate how other browsers and IE6 interpret this, consider this snippet:

```css
* {
  color: black;
}

.foo.bar {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">1. Hello Foo</div>
<div class="foo bar">2. Hello World</div>
<div class="bar">3. Hello Bar</div>
```

The page will look like this:

- On supported browsers:

  1. **Not selected** as this element only has class `foo`.
  2. **Selected** as this element has both classes `foo` and `bar`.
  3. **Not selected** as this element only has class `bar`.
- In Internet Explorer 6:

  1. **Not selected** as this element doesn't have class `bar`.
  2. **Selected** as this element has class `bar`, regardless of any other classes listed.
  3. **Selected** as this element has class `bar`.

Comment: Does it matter the order I put them in?

Comment: It doesn't matter. (It will for IE6 because of how it interprets it, assuming you must support it.)

Comment: Does it matter that there's no space between them?

Comment: @Imray: Yes, the space represents a descendant selector, which would make each class selector represent a different element. But we're talking about a single element here.

Comment: I suppose it works for N classes, right? Not just 2

Comment: @David Brossard: Yes, it does.

Comment: Works for classes and id's in any order:  .tab_active#tab1 and  #tab1.tab_active

Answer (score 10):

With SASS:

```scss
.foo {
  /* Styles with class "foo" */

  &.bar {
    /* Styles with class "foo bar" */
  }
}
```

See [What is the meaning of an ampersand in Less selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49401307/what-is-the-meaning-of-an-ampersand-in-less-selectors/49401539#49401539)

Answer (score 4):

It can be done by two ways in SCSS.

**Option 1**

```
.foo.bar {
    // Styles with class "foo bar"
}
```

**Option 2**

```
.foo {
   &.bar {
        // Styles with class "foo bar"
    }
 }
```