# Styling when element has two classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have been looking at the [w3 page on css selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) and have not found any promising leads, so I thought I would ask...

Is there a way to style a single element with two classes differently than if it was one class?

Example:

```css
a.foo {
  color: red;
}

a.bar {
  color: yellow;
}

a.foo.bar {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<a class="foo">Red</a>
<a class="bar">Yellow</a>
<a class="foo bar">Orange</a>
```

Comment: If you're looking to style an element with two specified classes, there's your answer. If *any two* classes, I'm not so sure about that.

Comment: What you have works. Note that IE6 does not support class overloading. It only recognizes the last class.

Comment: For an illustration of @Jason McCreary's point about IE6, see [my answer to a  duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes/3772305#3772305)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[You just answered yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/meder/tndf2/). Be wary of the [IE6 bug](http://work.arounds.org/issue/28/ie6-doesnt-support-chained-or-multiple-class-css-r/).

Comment: Thanks, I guess css is intuitive!

Comment: @superUntitled Do you still stand for that...? :)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah dude, you have just answered it yourself. Have a quick scan on these two pages -

1. http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/qt/tipcssmulticlas.htm
2. http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/multiple-classes/

Hope that helps :)

Nick