# when declaring css styles, what is the meaning of .classA.classB (two class names with a dot in the middle and no space)

Tags: css

I know when there is a space in between, it will look for the class on the right within the class on the left.

```
.classA .classB {
    ...
}
```

However, what does it look for when there is no space?

```
.classA.classB {
    ...
}
```

Comment: An element which contains both classes. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116288/css-select-an-element-with-2-class

Comment: @88MPG - You should post it as an answer...

Comment: @LcSalazar I'm sure 50 answers will pop up by the time I post one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Selector that applies to elements with two classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes), [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918742/css-styling-when-element-has-two-classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918742/css-styling-when-element-has-two-classes), [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796654/css-rule-to-apply-only-if-element-has-both-classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796654/css-rule-to-apply-only-if-element-has-both-classes)...

Comment: @88MPG - If you had posted it by the time you posted the comment, you would be upvoted instead of answers popping up...

Comment: @LcSalazar You're right, I posted an answer with some syntax examples and references.

Comment: Thanks all for the quick reply

Comment: @War10ck - agree that those posts are about same topic. However, those posts are asking the question from the other direction. In other words, they are asking how to do something, whereas my question was, I found something in the code but I don't know what it is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example (space-separated classes) is a parent-child relationship. `.classB` is found inside `.classA`.

```
<div class="classA">
    <div class="classB"></div>
</div>
```

The second is for one element with multiple classes, like so:

```
<div class="classA classB"></div>
```

Very different situations, but both extremely useful!

Further reading here:
[css select an element with 2 class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116288/css-select-an-element-with-2-class)
http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

It's used when you need an element, with both classes.

```
<div class="classA classB"></div>
```

would match

```
.classA.classB{}
```

See also:
http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

In the first example `.classA .classB` you're selecting elements with the class `classB` that are descendants of elements that have `classA`.

In the second example `.classA.classB` you're selecting elements that have **both** classes `classA` and `classB`.