# JQuery/CSS require multiple classes

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible in jQuery or CSS (since I think they use the same selector logic) to say select elements that have multiple classes. For example:

```
<div class='class1'></div>
<div class='class2'></div>
<div class='class1 class2'></div>
```

Is there a way I can say I want elements that are of both class1 and class2 (therefore only get the third div in this case)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The selector you are looking for is `.class1.class2`

For more info, check out the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html

Comment: If you care about IE6, it (unsurprisingly) treats `.class1.class2` exactly like `.class2`, see here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes/3772305#3772305 Either way this is the correct selector. (Not an issue if you're using jQuery, though, only with pure CSS.)