# Browser compatibility of some type of css selectors

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-selectors

I would like to know if where is any browsers that does not support this kind of select?

```
1) .class-1.class-2
2) #id-1.class-2
3) .class-1 > .class-2
4) .class-1 + .class-2
5) .class[foo="bar"]
```

I do not have so many different OS with different browsers...So don't know where can find these compatibility. So please give me a hand!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE7 and newer, as well as all other browsers, support all your given selectors.

1. IE6 reads `.class-1.class-2` as `.class-2` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes/3772305#3772305) for a comparison)
2. IE6 parses `#id-1.class-2` correctly
3. IE6 cannot read `>`, ignores entire rule completely
4. IE6 cannot read `+`, ignores entire rule completely
5. IE6 cannot read `[foo="bar"]`, ignores entire rule completely

Answer (score 2):

internet explorer 5 & 6 don't support `>`,`+` and `[attr]` selector. More information at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 1):

There is an extremely good site called Quirksmode.org which has a full set of compatibility charts for all CSS selectors and features.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

For what its worth, you'll have problems with almost all of those with IE6, but most other browsers will cope with them all just fine.

The solution: Don't support IE6.