# How to format a class class inside an id?

Tags: css, class, css-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="wrapper clear">
    <!-- stuff -->
  </div>
<div>
```

What do I put in the css file to format the div that has a class of wrapper and clear, but only when within the footer?

This is for use with wordpress.com, so I can't alter the HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this selector:

```
#footer .wrapper.clear
```

Note that IE6 doesn't handle multiple class selectors correctly, it treats the above as this (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes/3772305#3772305) for a comparison):

```
#footer .clear
```

But in most cases this should not matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
#footer div[class="wrapper clear"] { /* your awesome CSS code */}
```

Comment: **You don't select classes using the attribute selector!**

Comment: Although true, it works too (I got miscarried away by the separated list of values selector (div[class~='wrapper'])). Never used that in my code, though.