# How to select an element with 2 classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

i have this elements

```
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
```

I want apply to element with class a and b the color #666.
How can I do this with CSS?

Answer (score 421, accepted):

You can chain class selectors *without a space* between them:

```
.a.b {
     color: #666;
}
```

Note that, if it matters to you, IE6 treats `.a.b` as `.b`, so in that browser both `div.a.b` and `div.b` will have gray text. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes/3772305#3772305) for a comparison between proper browsers and IE6.

Comment: notice that .a .b is treated as .a and then .b

Comment: I think what @HoangHuynh means is that selector `.a .b` will match elements of class `.b` which are contained inside of elements of class `.a`.

Answer (score 30):

Just chain them together:

```
.a.b {
  color: #666;
}
```