# Different colors for each active menu item in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a menu in WordPress site with 4 items
- Home
- Portfolio
- Team
- Connect

I want to highlight menu item of current page being visited but each page should have different color. For example if I visit home page the Home menu item should be green.

[image]

If I visit portfolio page then portfolio menu item should be green.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Since theme is based on Twitter Bootstrap an .active class is added to the current page's menu item being visited. Therefore, I added a separate class like .home for home page, .portfolio to portfolio page, and then **chain the classes** to take effect like this.

```
.navbar-nav > .home.active > a {
    color: green !important;
}
```

Notice the .home.active classes are chained.

Following threads on SO were helpful.

[css select an element with 2 class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116288/css-select-an-element-with-2-class)

[CSS Selector that applies to elements with two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes)

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
ul li.active:first-child {
  color:blue;
}

ul li.active:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}


ul li.active:nth-child(3) {
    color: green;
}
```