# Overriding effect of one css by applying one more css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have 2 css classes , `.c1` and `.c2` , `.c1` applies `padding-top` of x and `.c2` of y, now I want to `.c1` to override `padding-top` value applied by `.c2`. How can I do it? I cannot alter `.c2` so I have to make `.c1` override some property values applied by `.c2`.

Comment: Can you show an example? Can you make `c1` get loaded after `c2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either move `.c1`'s rule below `.c2`'s:

```
.c2 { padding-top: 1em; }
.c1 { padding-top: 0.5em; }
```

or if your element has both classes, apply the style to another selector with [both classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes/3772305#3772305) `.c2.c1`:

```
.c1 { padding-top: 0.5em; }
.c2 { padding-top: 1em; }
.c2.c1 { padding-top: 0.5em; }
```

If you can't move the rules and can't style multiple classes, the last resort is using `!important`:

```
.c1 { padding-top: 0.5em !important; }
.c2 { padding-top: 1em; }
```

Comment: sorry , dint get you , can i use important?

Comment: @jslearner: Edited my answer. You can use it but the first two are better alternatives.

Comment: Using `.c1.c1 { padding-top: 0.5em; }` is independent of the order of rules, avoids duplication of the selector as in `.c1, .c1.c2` and also avoids `!important`. :D

Answer (score 1):

you can change the [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) of the selector that inludes `c1` or if you don't want to change it and it's the same to move it below the `c2` or, in the worst case, to add [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) for the property.

**Specificity demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ADBAf/

```
div span.c1 {color:blue}
.c2 {color:red}
```

**!important demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/ADBAf/1/

```
.c1 {color:blue !important}
.c2 {color:red}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `!important`

```
.c2{
  background-color:white;
}
.c1{
  background-color:green !important;
}
```

The `c1` color will be applied

Comment: `!important` won't be necessary if you put `.c1` after `.c2`.

Comment: You're putting `.c1` before `.c2` in your fiddle.

Comment: Ah, your right.  I shouldn't try to answer questions first thing in the morning :-(  http://jsfiddle.net/KFKsr/

Answer (score 0):

If you have no control over the placement of the rules, just do

```
.c1 { padding-top: 10px !important }
```

Otherwise it is enough to put the `.c1` rule under the `.c2` one (unless the latter is more specific).

Answer (score 0):

you have to apply 'Important ' in your CSS to do this

like this:-
.c1 { padding-top: 5  !important; }
.c2 { padding-top: 7; }