# multiple-class CSS inheritance problem in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css-selectors, internet-explorer-9, css

I have a class called ".spr" (for an image sprite) and many classes that alter the width, height and background-position attributes to show various parts of the sprite.

I also have ".on" classes to toggle between images appearing in an "on" or an "off" state.

The problem is that, in IE, the "on" class that should be associated with a certain class is being applied to a button that doesn't have that associated class (but a different one).

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**The CSS:**

```
.spr.burst.been {background-position: -241px -89px;
  .spr.burst.on {
    background-position: -301px -89px !important; }

  .spr.radiobutton {background-position: -250px -249px; }
    .spr.radiobutton.on {
background-position: -250px -218px;
      border: 3px dashed red; }
```

As you can see, IE9 interprets the class

```
.spr.radiobutton.on
```

as

```
.spr.on
```

and, since it comes later in the stylesheet, overrides the properties of

```
.spr.burst.on
```

*even though*

```
.spr.burst
```

does not have the class

```
.radiobutton
```

How can I properly apply these composite styles in IE?

Comment: Do you have document to try this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your page doesn't have a proper doctype declaration, IE9 will go into quirks mode and treat chained class selectors exactly like IE5/IE6 does: [it'll only read the last class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes/3772305#3772305) and apply rules accordingly.

As a result, the selector `.spr.radiobutton.on` is really being interpreted as just `.on` (rather than `.spr.on`), overriding the earlier rule that it thinks also has just the `.on` selector.

Simply give your document a doctype declaration and IE9 will behave as expected.

Comment: Always add a doctype declaration, regardless the browser. ;)

Comment: Just saved me some headache... thank you! IE9 is incredibly pessimistic to fall back to IE6 selector parsing >.<

Comment: Just what I was looking for! For hours I was wondering why ie9 was as cccccr@p as ie6!