# How to serve a different stylesheet if css3 is not supoorted by a browser?

Tags: jquery, css

I added lots of keyframe animations with css3 to my site. Lets say I am animating a div from left to right. Initialy the position of this div is -50px and I am animating to 0px, but if browser do not support css3 the user will see div at -50px which is bad.

How can I do something like:

if css3 is supported {
  css1.css
else {
  css2.css
}
}

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

there is no need to 2 different css files . 
you can use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com) with css to check if a browser supports css3 animation and decide upon the test .

all you need is to relocate the div if animation is not supported .

add modernizr to the page

add class="no-js" to html tag

if browser doesn't support css animations then "no-cssanimations" would be added to the class

then you can add custom rules for not-supporting browsers

```
.no-cssanimations #yourDiv
{
   top:0px;
}
```

check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087337/using-modernizr-with-css-classes-that-use-more-than-one-css3-style) that uses the same technique

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for you..

you can do this in javascript.    [Source](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-detect-css-support-in-browsers-with-javascript/#)

```
var supports = (function() {  
   var div = document.createElement('div'),  
      vendors = 'Khtml Ms O Moz Webkit'.split(' '),  
      len = vendors.length;  

   return function(prop) {  
      if ( prop in div.style ) return true;  

      prop = prop.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(val) {  
         return val.toUpperCase();  
      });  

      while(len--) {  
         if ( vendors[len] + prop in div.style ) {  
            // browser supports box-shadow. Do what you need.  
            // Or use a bang (!) to test if the browser doesn't.  
            return true;  
         }   
      }  
      return false;  
   };  
})();  

if ( supports('textShadow') ) { 
  $('#support').html("Your browser supports textShadow property");  
}
```

here is working fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/MehjK/

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good way to check if a browser supports css3 . supporting css3 new features in different browsers is not the same and even one browser support some features but not others . for example opera supports text shadow but not keyframes as far as I know

Comment: @reza good point..  it is better to know if a perticular property is supported before using it, instead of checking FULL CSS3 support.