# How to apply CSS to elements that have multiple classes?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to apply a style to elements that contain multiple classes?

#### Example

---

```
<div class="foo"     > foo     </div>
<div class="foo bar" > foo bar </div>
<div class="bar"     > bar     </div>
```

---

I only want to modify the styling of the element that contains class "foo bar".  The XPath information would be something like `//div[contains(@class,"foo") and contains(@class,"bar")]`.  Any ideas for pure CSS, w/o having to create a unique class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solutions

---

1. ```
    .foo.bar { ... }
   ```
2. ```
    [class="foo bar"] { ... }             // explicit class name
   ```
3. ```
    [class~="foo"][class~="bar"] { ... }  // inclusive class name
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
.foo { background: red; }
.bar { background: blue; }
.foo.bar { background: purple; }
```

Comment: If only it would KNOW that red and blue make purple - it could do this automagically!  ;)

Comment: Probably not worth mentioning, but just in case, IE6 has some issues with this. @BoltClock explains it well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes/3772305#3772305

Comment: In IE6: `e.c1.c2...cn` = `e.cn` where `e` is an element and `ci` is a class with position `i`.

Comment: @thirtydot: If I had seen that question I probably wouldn't have wasted my time asking :) --- and I did search SO and google :) -- could you check on attribute selectors in IE6

Comment: @vol7ron: IE6 simply does not support attribute selectors, like those in your answer.

Comment: @thirtydot: I figured :-/, fortunately IE6 is almost 4 versions in the past and, really, no longer has to be supported; much like IE5.5 is no longer supported.