# css: element.class.class - what does it mean?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here is a code snippet:

```
div.note.note_expanded
```

What does it mean? I understand div.className, but what is the second dot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A div that has the class note and note_expanded at the same time

Something like `<div class='note note_expanded'>` would match that.

Comment: Obligatory link to IE6 nonsense explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes/3772305#3772305

Comment: @BoltClock: I think we as developers have a responsibility to form a league of extraordinary developers mainly to go around an punch anyone who still uses that browser.

Answer (score 2):

This would target a `div` that has both a class of `.note` and a class of `.note_expanded`.

`<div class="note note_expanded">I'm special!</div>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
div.note.note_expanded {
  color:blue;
}
div.note {
  color:red;
}
div.note_expanded {
  color:black;
}
</style>
<div class='note note_expanded'> 
This is blue but I would think there must be an easier way.
</div>
```

Comment: when i remove the space from element .class {} to element.class {} mine stop working? why????