# how to find a css class which has another css class as sibling

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have two css classes A and B that are applied on the same element. I want to change class A only when it has class B as its sibling. Is there any css selector that can do this?

Comment: Now I'm confused - you say both classes are on the same element, but one is a sibling of the other? So how many elements are there?

Comment: May be the sibling term is causing confusion. There is only one element.
<a cls="A B" .../>
This class B is can be applied else where on some other elements. Like  <a cls="B".../> I want to find if this class B has class A along with it and only then add a few more properties into class B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply styles to different classes as usual:

```
.A {
    /* Styles for class A */
}

.B {
    /* Styles for class B */
}
```

Then chain both classes to apply more styles to elements only with both classes:

```
.A.B {
    /* Styles for elements with both classes A and B only */
}
```

Comment: [IE6 nonsense explained in this other answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes/3772305#3772305)

Comment: BoltClock, do you know if the classes can be in a different order than the css rule (eg. Class="A B" can match .B.A {} )?

Comment: @Zachary: It only matters if you're concerned with IE6. That's covered in the other answer I link to.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock. In the process of solving this issue I realized that if class B has a background property and I am trying to over write only the image using the background-image property in A, it does not work. That was causing problems for me.

Comment: BoltClock, thanks... I read it, but missed the question/answer in the comments.  Thanks...