# How to select classes with spaces

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How do I select a class like `class="boolean optional"` ?

I have tried this:

```
.boolean optional {CSS}

.boolean_optional {CSS}
```

Comment: those are actually two different classes.

Comment: Your first selector takes `optional` elements in elements with `class="boolean"`. Your second selector takes elements with `class="boolean_optional"`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

As Zepplock says, that's actually two classes in a single attribute: `boolean` and `optional`. The space is not part of a class name; it acts as the separator.

These three selectors will all match it:

```
.boolean
.optional
.boolean.optional
```

The last selector only picks up this element as it has *both* classes.

You *never* include a space when chaining class selectors, not even like this:

```
.boolean .optional
```

As that selects `.optional` elements that are contained within separate `.boolean` elements.

Comment: In IE6, `.boolean.optional` is equivalent to `.optional`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes/3772305#3772305

Answer (score 13):

Those are not classes with spaces :) They are called multiple class selectors.

You basically just need to make sure all the class names are connected (no spaces between them) and separated with a dot.

```
.boolean.optional {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Spaces are not valid in class name. `class="boolean optional"` means the element has the classes `boolean` *and* `optional`, so you can match it with either `.boolean`, `.optional`, or if you want to match only objects that are both optional and boolean, with `.boolean.optional`.

Answer (score 2):

Classes will never actually have spaces in their name.  In your example, that is actually two classes; `boolean` and `optional`.

to apply style to an element that has both of those classes, the construct is

```
.boolean.optional {
 /* CSS */
}
```

However, IE6 is known to have some issues with this.  See [this link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t14) for more details on known quirks.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this was a while ago, but in case anyone's interested, something I've found handy also is, how to target/select an element within an element which has both classes...
EXAMPLE

```
.boolean.optional > p {
    color: red;
}
```

Perhaps requires no explanation, but: turns 'paragraph text red' ONLY for paragraph's inside of elements where both classes exist i.e.both .boolean AND .optional