# How to reference a div with class="name1 name2"?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm working on some CSS from a tutorial, a div has this class:

```
<div class="related products">
```

How can I reference it in the stylesheet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select classes with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885013/how-to-select-classes-with-spaces)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `div` actually has two classes, `related` and `products`. You can reference it in your stylesheet with either `.related` or `.products`, and it will pick up the styles from both of those rules. For example, with the following CSS, the text in the `div` in your question would appear red with font size 12:

```
.related { color:#ff0000 }
.products { font-size:12px }
```

If you want to select elements with both classes, use `.related.products` in your stylesheet. For example, add the following to the above example:

```
.related.products { font-weight:bold }
```

And the text in your `div` will receive all three rules, because it matches all 3 selectors. Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/HKDvR/).

Answer (score 6):

`div.related.products` is the general method

Comment: Is the order significant, ie would `div.products.related` work too?

Comment: @ain: [Only for IE6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes/3772305#3772305) - for other browsers it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

You reference it by `div.related.products` which literaly translates to "a `div` with class of related and class of products".

Or, you could reference it by using **either** class names, since it will catch both.

[**jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/GRmRf/).

Answer (score -5):

In the css, just put the name class of the div by doing this:

```
.related products {
/*styling to go here*/
}
```

Now any styling within the related products class will be applied to that div.

Comment: This is not correct.  This selects any `<products>` children of a node with the class of `related`

Comment: WRONG! it will look for "a `<products>` element within an element with class of 'related' ".

Comment: Truth, remove the spaces in the div and in the css between the words products and related.

Comment: The space is there for a different reason, see the duplicate link.