# update button display on selecting radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've a code snippet like this, on selecting an option from radio button list like jan/feb/mar , the button should get updated. How to do it?

**code**

```
<div class="btn-group pull-left" style="margin-left:72px;">
    <button class="btn btn-success" align="center">Action</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value = "jan" onclick="check(this.value)">jan</label>
        </br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value = "feb" onclick="check(this.value)">feb</label>
        </br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value = "mar" onclick="check(this.value)">mar</label>
        </br>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function check(val)
{
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(val+' <span class="caret"></span>') 
}              
</script>
```

Comment: pls check the html ul child is li not label or input you can put the label and input inside li..check this `$(".dropdown-menu li a")` no li no a

Answer (score 0):

**javascript**

```
function check(val)
{
    document.querySelector('.btn.btn-success.dropdown-toggle').innerHTML=val+' <span class="caret"></span>'
}
```

[How to select classes with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885013/how-to-select-classes-with-spaces)

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp