# Css - targeting certain classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS Selector that applies to elements with two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes)

I've got the following:

```
<div class="green-arrow current-plan span4">
     <img src="/images/assets/green-arrow.jpg">
</div>

<div class="green-arrow plan-above span4">
     <img src="/images/assets/green-arrow.jpg">
</div>
```

And I want to target `plan-above` so it's `display: none;` **without affecting other instances** of `plan-above` (which are not `green-arrow`).

Comment: This has been asked before, search for "css multiple classes"

Comment: it would been really easy if you assign some id's

Comment: @stian.net: What purpose would IDs serve here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
div.green-arrow.plan-above {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Note: Hideously broken in IE6.

Comment: @Quentin Say something that isn't broken in IE6. ;) But seriously, IE6 is deprecated and no longer supported so I see no reason to (if not specifically requested) support that browser in your code.

Comment: @Filip — Enough people are still supporting it to make it worth mentioning when example code won't work in it. In ones own code, it is fine to decide not to support IE6. When teaching, on the other hand, it is a little more complex.

Comment: I went into grotesquely inordinate amounts of detail about IE6 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes If anybody is concerned about IE6, you can go ahead and vote to close future questions as duplicates of that specific one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
div.green-arrow.plan-above {
    display: none;
}
```

Further you can use CSS3 to excluded several classes comma seperated

```
div.plan-above:not(.class, #id) {
  //mark up
}
```

Comment: Still wrong, `:not()` in CSS3 **doesn't** allow comma-separated classes.

Comment: There is no such specification, but it works in FF3. Try it yourself

Comment: Why are you using *Firefox 3*? Firefox 9 is the current stable version.

Comment: It only works in Firefox 3 because it's a bug. It was fixed in I believe version 3.1 or 3.5.

Comment: I don't use Firefox. I'm stuck on Chrome. Read about it here: [Link](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/)

Comment: I've seen that article before, but it's really old. I've just [left a comment on it](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/comment-page-2/#comment-164654) to address this misconception, even though I doubt anybody reads comments on an old article anymore.