# CSS rule ".drop.a" being applied to class "drag a"

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, css-selectors

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div class="drag a"></div>
<div class="drop a"></div>
```

I also have the following CSS rule, which should only be applied to my 2nd div:

```
.drop.a
{
   background-color:red;
}
```

This is working fine, except in Internet Explorer 9 the CSS rule is being applied to both elements.

Why is this? I thought this kind of CSS was universally compatible with all browsers?

Comment: does it work if you make them classes of their own eg: drag_a and drop_a?

Comment: @Samwise I imagine it would, as these are then 2 seperate entire classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I thought this kind of CSS was universally compatible with all browsers?

Nope. [IE up to and including version 6 ignores all class selectors in a chain except the last one.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772305/106224) IE9 may be rendering your page in quirks mode, meaning it'll act like its predecessors, and treat your `.drop.a` selector as `.a` instead.

Try adding a doctype declaration to your page and see if that fixes it. If you already have one on your page and you're still seeing this behavior, something else is wrong.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I'm adding drag/drop functionality to a page which must have been created around early 2000's, and theres no doctype at the top, I didn't think to check. This has resolved my issue. I'll mark as answer in 6 mins