# what does "..." mean in css

Tags: html, css

i just wonder wht this would mean in the stylesheet part...once i get away with this stylesheet code, the entire page goes blank...

```
<style type="text/css">
...     
#wrapper {      
    display: none;  
}   

div[id="preloader"]{
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    width: 132px; height: 38px;
    background:
    url(path/to/preloaderBg.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: wait;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fefefe; //webkit 
}
...
</style>
```

the "..." is there at the start and the end of the stylesheet...

[image]

Comment: It doesn't mean anything, where did you see that?

Comment: Do you have some unusual server side post processing?

Comment: right..it doesn't mean anything just clear it up and test it again.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis

Comment: it clearly means "..." nthing else than that in css

Answer (score 4):

The horizontal ellipsis character has no meaning in CSS. It is a syntax error (except when part of a piece of freeform data (such as `content: "foo…bar";`). The same applies to three sequential period characters.

It could be a feature of the code viewer (or a code sample you are copying from) indicating that what is displayed is incomplete (as per the usual meaning of the character in typography).

Comment: It appears to be three periods rather than an ellipsis character, but either way it's still nonsense in CSS.

Comment: @BoltClock — I copy/pasted form the title of the question where it is an ellipsis … on the other hand, the screen shot is using a monospace font where it does look like three periods.

Comment: That makes sense. Also, although probably unrelated, [IE gives leading periods special treatment in class selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273227/triple-periods-in-front-of-css/14273657#14273657). In this case however, it's clear it's not being used as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

It just means other stuff not shown. No specific meaning in CSS.