# What is the css selector for class="c1 c2"

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS Selector that applies to elements with two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes)

So I have a '.data-label' class, that has a width and is designed to be part of a 'row' in a table like layout, but I'd also like to have an element with '.inline .data-label', which would dispense with the width but still keep the font settings from '.data-label'

What is the correct css selector for selecting 2 class at once?

Comment: I think you've answered this in your title. Having <div class="c1 c2"> would apply both classes - c1 and c2 - to that div. Unless I'm not understanding? EDIT: Looking at the duplicate post BoltClock has provided, I'm missing the point - check out his link.

Comment: Can you add the original and corrected css code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply

`.inline.data-label`

it should work.