# Using two CSS classes on one element

Tags: css, class

What am I doing wrong here?

I have a `.social` `div`, but on the first one I want zero padding on the top, and on the second one I want no bottom border.

I have attempted to create classes for this first and last but I think I've got it wrong somewhere:

```
.social {
    width: 330px;
    height: 75px;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #6d6d6d;
}

.social .first{padding-top:0;}

.social .last{border:0;}
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="social" class="first">
    <div class="socialIcon"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></div>
    <div class="socialText">Find me on Facebook</div>
</div>
```

I'm guessing it's not possible to have two different classes? If so how can I do this?

Comment: I created a simple example to demonstrate the difference between the descendent selector and the double-class selector: http://jsfiddle.net/jyAyX/.  Also, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors.

Comment: Just curious if I do: `<p class = "a" class = "b"></p>` will both rules be applied or just b or ... I am doing a quick and dirty alpha and was about to cut and paste class statements into lots of elements that did not have classes but a few do. Just trying to work out how this would be handled.  Have looked bit with no joy.

Comment: Also related (if not even considered as duplicate of): [CSS Selector that applies to elements with two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/)

Comment: @BeNice Only the first class attribute applies; the second one will be ignored. In your example, class = "a" will apply, class = "b" will be ignored.

Answer (score 670, accepted):

If you want two classes on one element, do it this way:

```
<div class="social first"></div>
```

Reference it in css like so:

```
.social.first {}
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/tybro0103/covbtpaq/

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware I could double up like that :) Good to know for the future!

Comment: What would happen if we had just `<div class="first"></div>` ?

Comment: @MarcoCastanho I updated answer with link to example

Comment: I just wanted to add the order which you reference the CSS element will not matter so you can also reference it in css like so: .first.social {} and it will be the same as .social.first {}

Comment: AAUUGH! I keep wanting to put a comma in between the two, so this helped me!

Comment: it is important to note that there is no space in between 2 classes. Spent 5 minutes figuring out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 42):

You can try this:

***HTML***

```
<div class="social">
    <div class="socialIcon"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></div>
    <div class="socialText">Find me on Facebook</div>
</div>
```

***CSS CODE***

```
.social {
  width:330px;
  height:75px;
  float:right;
  text-align:left;
  padding:10px 0;
  border-bottom:dotted 1px #6d6d6d;
}
.social .socialIcon{
  padding-top:0;
}
.social .socialText{
  border:0;
}
```

To add multiple class in the same element you can use the following format:

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3"></div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KDMfP/4/)**

Answer (score 31):

Remember that you can apply multiple classes to an element by separating each class with a space within its class attribute. For example:

```
<img class="class1 class2">
```

Answer (score 19):

If you have 2 classes i.e. `.indent` and `.font`, `class="indent font"` works.

You dont have to have a `.indent.font{}` in css.

You can have the classes separate in css and still call both just using the `class="class1 class2"` in the html. You just need a space between one or more class names.

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for me, although I also believe that it should work the way you've mentioned. Suspecting if my CSS classes being defined in two different stylesheets could be a factor. Need to investigate this.

Answer (score 10):

If you only have two items, you can do this:

```css
.social {
    width: 330px;
    height: 75px;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border: none;
}

.social:first-child { 
    padding-top:0;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #6d6d6d;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this post is getting outdated, but here's what they asked.
In your style sheet:

```
.social {
    width: 330px;
    height: 75px;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #6d6d6d;
}
[class~="first"] {
    padding-top:0;
}
[class~="last"] {
    border:0;
}
```

But it may be a bad way to use selectors. Also, if you need multiple "first" extension, you'll have to be sure to set different name, or to refine your selector.

```
[class="social first"] {...}
```

I hope this will help someone, it can be pretty handy in some situation.

For exemple, if you have a tiny piece of css that has to be linked to many different components, and you don't want to write a hundred time the same code.

```
div.myClass1 {font-weight:bold;}
div.myClass2 {font-style:italic;}
...
div.myClassN {text-shadow:silver 1px 1px 1px;}

div.myClass1.red {color:red;}
div.myClass2.red {color:red;}
...
div.myClassN.red {color:red;}
```

Becomes:

```
div.myClass1 {font-weight:bold;}
div.myClass2 {font-style:italic;}
...
div.myClassN {text-shadow:silver 1px 1px 1px;}

[class~=red] {color:red;}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to apply styles only to an element which is its parents' first child, is it better to use `:first-child` pseudo-class

```css
.social:first-child{
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #6d6d6d;
    padding-top: 0;
}
.social{
    border: 0;
    width: 330px;
    height: 75px;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Then, the rule `.social` has both common styles and the last element's styles.

And `.social:first-child` overrides them with first element's styles.

You could also use `:last-child` selector, but `:first-child`is more supported by old browsers: see 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:first-child#Browser_compatibility and https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/:last-child#Browser_compatibility.

Comment: To see if you can use :last-child and :first-child in other browsers check: https://caniuse.com/#search=first-child

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use [Descendant selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)

HTML:

```
<div class="social">
<p class="first">burrito</p>
<p class="last">chimichanga</p>
</div>
```

Reference first one in CSS: `.social .first { color: blue; }`

Reference last one in CSS: `.social .last { color: green; }`

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/covbtpaq/153/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using multiple CSS classes, to address your underlying problem you can use the `:focus` pseudo-selector:

```
input[type="text"] {
   border: 1px solid grey;
   width: 40%;
   height: 30px;
   border-radius: 0;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
   border: 1px solid #5acdff;
}
```