# How can i run lazy load on already giving class?

Tags: lazy-loading

I can able to install a lazy load of those images where i haven't given the class, so the lazy load class="lazy" will add to the image to work properly BUT how can i add the lazy load class to that image where i have already given the class name like for example

```
<img src="img/mobimg.png" alt="mob image" class="mobimg" />
```

--> Now where to add a lazy load class. I tried adding two classes but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is [Using two CSS classes on one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918491/using-two-css-classes-on-one-element)

the way it would work for you