# Rails New Action with Different Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I've got an issue in Rails with the create action - I have this information in my controller:

```
ComputerController 
def create
  @computer = Computer.new(computer_params)
  redirect_to computers_path
end

private  
 def computer_params
 require.params(:computer).permit(:computer_name,
 :cpu_tag,:serial,:location,:brand,:model,:ram,:cpu,:os,:warranty,:comments)  
end
```

Then in my model I have some validations:

```
class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :computer_name,  uniqueness: true, presence: true,
 length:{maximum: 12} 
 validates :cpu_tag, length: {maximum: 4}, uniqueness: true, 
 :numericality =>   {:only_integer => true}
 validates :serial, presence: true
 validates :location, presence: true
 validates :brand, presence: true
 validates :model, presence: true
 validates :ram, presence: true
 validates :cpu, presence: true
 validates :os, presence: true
 validates :warranty, presence: true
 validates :comments, presence: true
end
```

The view new.html.erb is:

```
<div class="row text-center">
 <h2 class = "mimsinfoblackindex">Add A Computer To The Inventory </h2><hr/>

<div class="col-md-3 description_pc text-left">
   <%= form_for @computer do |f|%>  

    <h4 class = "mimsformgreen">
      <%= f.label :computer_name,'Computer Name:'%>
      <%= f.text_field :computer_name%>
    </h4>

    <h4 class = "mimsformblack">
      <%= f.label :cpu_tag, 'Computer Tag:'%>
      <%= f.text_field :cpu_tag%>
    </h4>

    <h4 class = "mimsformblack">
      <%= f.label :serial, 'Serial:'%>
      <%= f.text_field :serial%>
    </h4>

    <h4 class = "mimsformblack">
      <%= f.label :location, 'Location:'%> 
      <%= f.text_field :location%>
    </h4>

    <h4 class = "mimsformblack">
      <%= f.label :brand, 'Brand:'%>
      <%= f.text_field :brand%>
    </h4>

    <h4 class = "mimsformblack">
      <%= f.label :model, 'Model:'%>
      <%= f.text_field :model%>
    </h4>

    <h4 class = "mimsformblack">
      <%= f.label :ram, 'Ram:'%> 
      <%= f.text_field :ram%>
    </h4>

    <h4 class = "mimsformblack">  
      <%= f.label :cpu, 'Processor:'%>
      <%= f.text_field :cpu %>
    </h4>

    <h4 class = "mimsformblack">
      <%= f.label :os, 'Operating System:'%> 
      <%= f.text_field :os%>
    </h4>

    <h4 class = "mimsformblack">
      <%= f.label :warranty, 'Warranty:'%>
      <%= f.text_field :warranty%>
    </h4>

     <h4 class = "mimsformblack">
      <%= f.label :comments, 'Comments:'%>
      <%= f.text_field :comments%>
    </h4>

        <%= f.submit 'Add The Computer'%>
  <% end %>
```

I already did TDD for my models and I don't have any problems, but when I submit the computer form, I get an error message in the screen that says:

```
 wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
 private  
 def computer_params
  require.params(:computer).permit(:computer_name,:cpu_tag,
  :serial,:location,:brand,:model,:ram,:cpu,:os,:warranty,:comments)  
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to the answer, there are some fixes you could make with your code:

---

## 1 Validations

When defining the same `presence` validation, you can [pass multiple arguments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) (attributes) to the method:

```
#app/models/computer.rb
class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :serial, :location, :brand, :model, :ram, :cpu, :os, :warranty, :comments, presence: true
end
```

---

## 2 Params

Rails' [`strong params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) functionality is pretty specific in stating you need to "require" a top-level param, and then "permit" its child params:

```
def computer_params
  params.require(:computer).permit(:computer_name,:cpu_tag, :serial,:location,:brand,:model,:ram,:cpu,:os,:warranty,:comments)  
end
```

---

## 3 Loops

In programming, the most efficient code wins.

This means you should not be replicating a bunch of code time & time again (using the [`attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/attributes) method):

```
#app/views/computers/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @computer do |f| %>

    <% @computer.attributes.each do |attr| %>
       <% xtra = "green" if attr == :computer_name %>
       <%= content_tag :h4, class: "misform #{xtra}" do %>
          <%= f.label attr.to_sym, attr.titleize + ":" %>
          <%= f.text_field attr.to_sym %>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit 'Add The Computer'%>
<% end %>
```

See how much cleaner that is?

---

## 4 HTML Classes

You've used these two class names:

`mimsformblack`
`mimsformgreen`

Looking at my `#3` recommendation, can you see how this is very inefficient? It's violates a principle called [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), in which you're meant to use as little code with as much functionality as possible.

You can apply [multiple CSS classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918491/using-two-css-classes-on-one-element) to each element, which means you'll be able to do the following:

```
<div class="mimsform">This will be black</div> 
<div class="mimsform green">This will be green</div>
```

---

## 5 Create

When you *create* in Rails, you have to *save* the object to the model:

```
def create
  @computer = Computer.new computer_params
  redirect_to computers_path if @computer.save
end
```

Many newbie developers don't save their new object, preventing them from actually saving the data to the db.

Comment: Hi Rich Many thanks for the help, i'm new in ROR so i appreciate all the recommendations for my code, and specially that kind of recommendations for be a better developer, thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

Try rewriting your `computer_params` to:

```
private  

def computer_params
  params.require(:computer).permit(:computer_name, :cpu_tag, :serial, :location, :brand, :model, :ram, :cpu, :os, :warranty, :comments)  
end
```

It appears that `params` and `require` are reversed in your original code.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Zoran, that was the mistake.. sorry rookie mistake i'm new on ROR and i don't pay attention to that part of the code...