# Changing multiple pages' CSS that share a common class

Tags: html, css

I want to change the padding of 2/6 pages in my website, but the content divs of the website are using the same CSS, the only solution I can think of is changing the id's of all the content divs and make separate CSS for all of them. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Use javascript.

Comment: No, don't use javascript. Just add another class to your elements. Also for the future: https://smacss.com/

Comment: Give html/body/any other common ancestor element an id or class, and use that to format their descendants differently ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new class and apply it to only the places you want changed.

```
.pad-class{
  padding:5px;
}

<div class="other-class pad-class"></div>
```

Placing the class last will allow for your new class to overwrite the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You should just apply a specific class to the `<body>` tag of the pages you want to modify. Then you can write a CSS rule for that class.

HTML (normal page)

```
<body>
  ...
</body>
```

HTML (different padding page)

```
<body class="different-padding">
  ...
</body>
```

CSS

```
<style>
body { padding: 10px; }
body.different-padding { padding: 20px; } 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="first second"></div>
```

Insert second where you want to change padding else keep only single class
further reference: [Using two CSS classes on one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918491/using-two-css-classes-on-one-element)

you can also use inline styling if no. of divs are less