# single identifier for multiple css classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have frequent bundling together of css classes like this:

```
<div class="row z-depth-2 gradient-background">
... Blah
</div>
```

I have these three classes: `row z-depth-2 gradient-background` used together in more than 200 places. How can I introduce a single class for these three taken together?

I don't mind CSS or SASS. One other problem is that `row` and `z-depth-2` are defined in `materialize.css` which I don't wanna touch. So I can't simply extend these classes in SASS like so:

```
.input-group {
    @extend .row, .z-depth-2, .gradient-background
}
```

So I want to be able to do something like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
    ... Blah
</div>
```

Comment: What is real target? Set styles to these three classes when they are used together? Replace them in your HTML markup by `class="input-group"`? Or...?

Comment: @panther, Yes. Updated the question with the intention because it's been flagged as unclear.

Comment: why not simply use this selector `.row.z-depth-2.gradient-background` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you provide an answer? I'm a bit new to css.

Comment: Could you not combine all applicable style statements from those separate rules into one style block? So, take all styles from `.row`, `.z-depth-2`, and `.gradient-background` and combine them into one style rule `input-group`.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError: This is exactly what I want to do. But, `.row` and `.z-depth` are defined in `materialize.css` and there's no way that I'm gonna redo those stylings again. I just want a simple way to specify that wherever `input-group` is specified as class, it should expand to `row z-depth-2 .gradient-background`. That's it.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you mean by *expand* - but the only way I can see you doing this is if you **copy** all the required style statements from the classes in question and declare them under your own custom style block; which would be `input-group` - then when using `.input-group` as a class, you'll know it is essentially a combination of all style rules from the required classes. If you are expecting something more *dynamic*, I don't think this can be done with standard CSS syntax.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError i think he want to have a Preprocessing script that wil change the `input-group` into these 3 classes. Of course something we cannot use with pure CSS. So he need to write one selector and at the end it's rendred as the 3 others

Comment: So, I take it that this is impossible to do with CSS? SASS would have worked, but I depend on the materialize classes (`.row` and `z-depth-2`). So I can't import it. Looks like there's no way around this.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use the three classes as one selector like this `.row.z-depth-2.gradient-background`. It will allow you to select elements that have these 3 classes (it can have more of course) :

```css
div {
  margin:10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
}

.row.z-depth-2.gradient-background {/* pay attention as there is no spaces between the classes*/
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row z-depth-2 gradient-background">
<!-- Select this one -->
</div>
<div class="row gradient-background">

</div>

<div class="row z-depth-2">

</div>

<div class="row gradient-background z-depth-2 more-class">
<!-- Select this one -->
</div>
```

Usefull links to get more details :

https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

[Using two CSS classes on one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918491/using-two-css-classes-on-one-element)

**UPDATE**

If you want to use a new class that will later be replaced with these 3 ones, you can use a small jQuery script in order to do what you need, like this :

```js
//select all element with class input-group
$('.input-group').each(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('input-group'); //remove input-group
  $(this).addClass('row z-depth-2 gradient-background'); //add the other classes
})
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
}

.row.z-depth-2.gradient-background {
  /* pay attention as there is no spaces between the classes*/
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">

</div>
<div class="class">

</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't do what I was hoping to do. I just want to be able to do this:

`<div class="input-grouping">...` and have it expand to `<div class="row z-depth-2 gradient-background">...`.

Comment: To clarify, I don't want to have a "different style" for `.row.z-depth-2.gradient-background` selector. I just want to give that selector a single name. That's it.

Comment: @nakiya will  a JS solution ok ? i provided one in my updated answer

Comment: Sorry, don't wanna do JS solution. I was under the impression that this is doable in CSS/SASS. Looks like it's impossible. Thanks for the time.