# Two classes in one input unable to send keys

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I have following input

```
<input type="text" class="input-small note-editable"/>
```

How can i get access to that input to send keys?
So far i was trying this:

```
this.inputForm = element(by.css('.input-small .note-editable'));
```

and

```
this.inputForm = element(by.css('.input-small'));
this.inputForm2 = this.inputForm.element(by.css('.note-editable'));
```

But it doesn't work, any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a selector for *both* classes, not subsequent elements, so try:

```
this.inputForm = element(by.css('.input-small.note-editable'));
```

See [CSS Selector that applies to elements with two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes) for more examples / discussion