# Change CSS of Bootstrap-Columns created by AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I try to display some Employees with AngularJS and Bootstrap, but i am unable to override/change the CSS of my created bootstrap-columns (adding a shadow around every employee).

I think it has something to do with the CSS-specifics but I can not figure out what.

Index.html

```
<body data-ng-cloak="">
    <div class="webpage">
        <!-- Here is a banner with navigation -->
        <div ng-view class="content"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

AngularJS Partial:

```
<link href="styles/booking.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <div class="row search">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <!--Sidebar content-->
            Search by name: <input ng-model="query">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 employee" ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:{name:query}" ng-click="onClickEmployee($index)">
            {{employee.name | uppercase}}
           <p>{{employee.quote}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

booking.css

```
.webpage .content .ng-scope .row .col-md-4 .employee {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ng-class`. Add some boolean value that will contain info about whether to trigger add the class or remove it from the element (e.g. by `ng-click` or `ng-mouseover`). More about `ng-class`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass.

If it is problem with css only then try `!important`.

```
.webpage .content .ng-scope .row .col-md-4 .employee {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000 !important;
}
```

EDIT:

I see you added space between `.col-md-4` and `.employee`.

```
.webpage .content .ng-scope .row .col-md-4.employee {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
```

Comment: Your edited version works great! And here is the reason why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes. Thank You!