# if class and class show certain css

Tags: html, css

Code:

```
<div class="mgu-teaser-slide-left mgu-rot">
    <div class="mgu-teaser-slider-bubble">blabla</div>
</div>
or
<div class="mgu-teaser-slide-left mgu-gelb">
    <div class="mgu-teaser-slider-bubble">blabla</div>
</div>
```

Now I'm looking for a solution where I can tell the class `mgu-taser-slider-bubble` to show a certain background-img if "`mgu-teaser-slide-left` and `mgu-rot`" or another if "`mgu-teaser-slide-left` and `mgu-gelb`". I need this combination because at the end it should show the background left or right aligned (there will be an other class "mgu-teaser-slide-right" at the end).

I've tried like that (which doesn't work!):

```
.mgu-teaser-slide-left .mgu-rot .mgu-teaser-slider-bubble { background: url('...'); }
```

thanks for help

Comment: You have to read the css documentation again. The issue is that you have spaces between the class names. Have a try with `.mgu-teaser-slide-left.mgu-rot` instead... (directly concatenated)

Comment: Related: [Multiple Class / ID and Class Selectors](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/) on CSS-tricks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Selector that applies to elements with two classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

Since class **.mgu-teaser-slide-left** **.mgu-rot** are on same element,access it with

```
.mgu-teaser-slide-left.mgu-rot
```

```css
.mgu-teaser-slide-left.mgu-rot .mgu-teaser-slider-bubble { 
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="mgu-teaser-slide-left mgu-rot">
    <div class="mgu-teaser-slider-bubble">blabla</div>
</div>
or
<div class="mgu-teaser-slide-left mgu-gelb">
    <div class="mgu-teaser-slider-bubble">blabla</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't just flash out some code, that's hardly helpful for others who come here and see your answer. Always provide explanation.

Comment: was adding the explanation as well. your comment beat me in saving that, may be by 40 odd seconds

Comment: are you afraid someone would beat you with a correct answer? SO is actually not a contest...

Comment: @giorgio dont you think its better to appraise people for helping someone without gaining anything. 40 seconds should be given at least for better explanation. May be you get some actual prize by giving some answer here but i never

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this:

```
 .mgu-teaser-slide-left.mgu-gelb .mgu-teaser-slider-bubble {
     …
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ph9ka5c4

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate CSS classes for **AND** and use multiple CSS rules with commas for **OR**:

```
.mgu-teaser-slide-left.mgu-rot .mgu-teaser-slider-bubble,
.mgu-teaser-slide-left.mgu-gelb .mgu-teaser-slider-bubble { 
  background: url('...');
}
```