# combine multiple css styles into one

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've got `div` that uses several styles

```
<div class="alert alert-secondary login-alert" role="alert">Please contract administrator to recieve credentials!</div>
```

Where `alert` and `alert-secondary` are default `bootstrap 4` styles while  `login-alert` is just a simple one-liner

```
.login-alert {
    font-family: 'Kavivanar', cursive;
}
```

How to combine it into one style? The thing is that I want to use that combined style only in certain places and I might need pure `alert` or `alert-secondary` somewhere.

Comment: Take the css of those 3 classes and merge it into one class ? I don't quite seem to understand.

Comment: Can you give the css for alert and alert-secondary ?

Comment: Not sure why you want to combine them in one and not use the 3 like you do now, and when you need just `alert` use that when you need 2 use those, etc..

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell They are [`Bootstrap 4` classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/)

Comment: Then look in the bootstrap css files for those classes, and copy the css for them, and combine them into 1 class. Why don't you just use class: "alert alert-secondary login-alert" when you want to combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap 4, the css for .alert is

```
.alert {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

and for .alert-secondary

```
.alert-secondary {
    color: #464a4e;
    background-color: #e7e8ea;
    border-color: #dddfe2;
}
```

So to combine them, use:

```
.login-alert-combined{
    font-family: 'Kavivanar', cursive;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    color: #464a4e;
    background-color: #e7e8ea;
    border-color: #dddfe2;
}
```

But I don't see what is wrong with setting class as "alert alert-secondary login-alert" when you want to use all 3 styles.

Comment: well I don't like having style for just one property

Comment: Is 'contract' a typo of 'contact' in 'Please contract administrator' ? I just noticed.

Comment: by the way when I do like this, it hides the button

Answer (score 0):

try concatenating both classes in your css

```
.alert.alert-secondary{
    font-family: 'Kavivanar', cursive;
}
```

Note that this will give the property to all your `div`'s that has both `alert` and `alert-secondary` classes.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes) that explains it better.