# What is the meaning of an ampersand in Less selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I download a project, and in it there use `less` write the stylesheet.
And in the script code the `name: own-space`, and in the `less` code, there are `&-btn-box`, `&-tra` and `&-input-identifycode-con` selectors.

I have two questions:

- I don't know the `.own-space` in less and the `name: own-space`'s relationship.
- and what's the meaning of `&-btn-box`, `&-tra` and `&-input-identifycode-con` there? what's the function of them?

My code is below:

```
    <template>
      <div>
        .....
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>

      export default {
        components: {



        },
        name: 'own-space',
        data () {
          ...
          };
        },
        methods: {
          ...
        }
      };
    </script>
    <style lang="less" rel="stylesheet/less">

      ...

      .own-space {

        &-btn-box {
          margin-bottom: 10px;

          button {
            padding-left: 0;

            span {
              color: #2D8CF0;
              transition: all .2s;
            }

            span:hover {
              color: #0C25F1;
              transition: all .2s;
            }
          }
        }

        &-tra {
          width: 10px;
          height: 10px;
          transform: rotate(45deg);
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          margin-top: -6px;
          left: -3px;
          box-shadow: 0 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
          background-color: white;
          z-index: 100;
        }
   
        &-input-identifycode-con {
          position: absolute;
          width: 200px;
          height: 100px;
          right: -220px;
          top: 50%;
          margin-top: -50px;
          border-radius: 4px;
          box-shadow: 0 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        }
 
      }

    </style>
```

Comment: Note there's difference between `&btn-box` and `&<newline>btn-box` (the latter is equivalent to `& btn-box` and then the initially posted code did not make too much sense). I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Less/Sass and other pre-processors let you write the CSS code with nested rules (besides other things like variables, mixins, and so on). So you don't have to write the full path like you do in CSS. You can just nest the style.

For example, you could have a structure like:

```html
<parent>
    <child>
        <grandchild>
        </grandchild>
    </child>
</parent>
```

In plain CSS, to style every element you would write:

```css
parent { styles }
parent child { styles }
parent child grandchild { styles }
```

With Less (and other preprocessors like SCSS) you can do the following

```css
parent {
    some parent styles 
    & child {
        some child styles 
        & grandchild {
             some grandchild styles
        }
    }
 &:hover { hover styles on parent }
 &:before { pseudo element styles }
}
```

etc.

So, the use of `&` **can** be to enable style writing for elements that are in a relationship with the parent element ( in your case the `.own-space` ).

`btn-box` , `-tra` , `-input-identifycode-con` are direct children of the `own-space` element, and `button`  is child of `btn-box` , `span` is child of `button`, grandchild of `btn-box` and , grandgrandchild ( :) ) of the `own-pace`. Anyway, you get the ideea :)

For the specific question  `.own-space { &-btn-box { ... } }` would mean that there is an element with class `own-space-btn-box` which most probably is a child of `own-space` but **NOT** necessarily ( see end of answer ). The HTML seems to be structured in a [BEM style](http://getbem.com/introduction/) but not according to the documentation and rules. When using preprocessors for styling it is highly recommended to use the BEM naming strategy. Take a look at it.

For example, the current structure COULD look like:

<sub>Stack Snippets do not accept SCSS. You can check out a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qf1n0ak4/1/)</sub>

```css
.own-space {

        &-btn-box {
          margin-bottom: 10px;

          button {
            padding-left: 0;

            span {
              color: #2D8CF0;
              transition: all .2s;
            }

            span:hover {
              color: #0C25F1;
              transition: all .2s;
            }
          }
        }

        &-tra {
          width: 10px;
          height: 10px;
          transform: rotate(45deg);
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          margin-top: -6px;
          left: -3px;
          box-shadow: 0 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
          background-color: white;
          z-index: 100;
        }

        &-input-identifycode-con {
          position: absolute;
          width: 200px;
          height: 100px;
          right: -220px;
          top: 50%;
          margin-top: -50px;
          border-radius: 4px;
          box-shadow: 0 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        }

      }
```

```html
<div class="own-space">
  The SO snippet doesn't support CSS preprocessors.
   Example purposes only 
    <div class="own-space-btn-box">
      <button>Button</button>
      <span>Some span</span>
    </div>
    <div class="own-space-tra">
       Tra tra
    </div>
    <div class="own-space-input-identifycode-con">
      identifycode
    </div>
</div>
```

**IMPORTANT** when you see styles like these in most cases the elements **ARE** related but keep in mind when debugging other people's code that it's not always the case. They can be **unrelated**, e.g.

```html
<element class="element"> ....  </element>
<element2 class="element-element2"> ....  </element2>
```

The SCSS could still look like this and have the same effect

```css
.element { 
   styles
    &-element2 {
     styles
   }
}
```

See example -> [not related](https://jsfiddle.net/qf1n0ak4/2/)

Another example use of `&` would be in the case you have two elements with a common class and a specific class, e.g.

```html
 <element class="element specific1">....</element>
 <element class="element specific2">....</element>
```

You can add common styles and specific styles all together like

```css
.element { 
   /* common styles */
   &.specific1 {
     /* specific 1 styles */
   }
   &.specific2 {
     /* specific 2 styles */
   }
}
```

There are a lot of different uses for `&`. Read more:

- [the-sass-ampersand](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/)
- [Sass parent selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector)
- [LESS](http://lesscss.org/features/)
- [BEM naming](http://getbem.com/naming/)

Comment: In your "grandchild" Less  example the result for the most nested selector would be `parentchildgrandchild`. I..e. notice the difference between `&identifier` and `& identifier` (`&` in the latter is normally omitted since it's redundant).

Comment: It would also make sense to link to the language docs (e.g. "For more details see [Parent Selectors](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature)").