# How to use joint selectors in styled-component

Tags: reactjs, css, styled-components

I have legacy CSS which looks like this:

```css
.btn_1 {
    color: #fff;
    background: #004dda;
    display: inline-block;
}
.btn_1:hover {
  background-color: #FFC107;
  color: #222 !important;
}
.btn_1.full-width {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I want to migrate to using styled-components (CSS-in-JS style) in React.

This is my migration so far:

```css
.btn_1 {
    color: #fff;
    background: #004dda;
    display: inline-block;
    :hover {
        background-color: #FFC107;
        color: #222 !important;
    }
}
```

but is there any solution in styled-components for selectors like `.btn_1.full-width` or I should just create another CSS block for that?

---

I think it would be cool to do something like this (or better):

```css
.btn_1 {
    ${this}.full-width {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
   }
}
```

but I can't seem to find the solution in the documents. Do you have any idea how this is possible or is this even a good idea?

Comment: For *joint* selectors follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes.   Note that there is no need to ${this}

Comment: Have you tried using an ampersand `&` this is the common way for most CSS pre-processors.

Comment: @Mulli Thanks but I'm looking for a `styled-components` solution. I clearly know how to it in css3.

Comment: @GingerCSSWizard Man, `&.full-width` worked just fine! I wonder why no one talks about it in styled-components docs. Would you write an answer for future visitors?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

from [official styled components documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#coming-from-css)

For complex selector patterns, the ampersand (&) can be used to refer back to the main component. Here are some more examples of its potential usage:

```
const Thing = styled.div.attrs({ tabIndex: 0 })`
  color: blue;

  &:hover {
    color: red; // <Thing> when hovered
  }

  & ~ & {
    background: tomato; // <Thing> as a sibling of <Thing>, but maybe not directly next to it
  }

  & + & {
    background: lime; // <Thing> next to <Thing>
  }

  &.something {
    background: orange; // <Thing> tagged with an additional CSS class ".something"
  }

  .something-else & {
    border: 1px solid; // <Thing> inside another element labeled ".something-else"
  }
`
```

Comment: @Mehrad77  True! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ampersand to chain nested selectors.

```
.btn_1 {
    &.full-width {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
   }
}
```