# How to get the css selector if the class name has two words and there is no id

Tags: python, css

I am writing a web bot using selenium in Python. I tried to find elements by css selector, however the html for some elements has no id and has only class name. Some of these have two words as the class name.
If it was one word, I could've written .oneword, but it has two words. 
I actually don't know anything about css or js.
I am using this syntax

```
var=bot.find_element_by_css_selector('css-selector')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Selector that applies to elements with two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the element using xpath

> bot.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='value test']")

Refer this: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath

Comment: Thanks! It worked by xpath, so now I am using xpath instead of css-selector.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the space between two words by .(dot)

For Example  then by_css_selector('test1.test2)