# check if class exists vba

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

i am testing a code that checks if the item is out of stock on a given page. if the item is out of stock, the page contains a class:

class="stock out-of-stock">Out of stock

if not then the product is in stock. I have 2 links, one of which is out of stock, and the other is in stock and i have used query selectorAll to check ".stock out-of-stock" class exists and return false if it does not. My code returns True in both cases however.

```
Sub test()

Dim txt1 As String
Dim txt2 As String

txt1 = "https://www.cigarsofcuba.co.uk/shop/cuban-cigars/bolivar-cigars/bolivar-belgravia-uk-regional-2015-cigars-box-of-10/"
txt2 = "https://www.cigarsofcuba.co.uk/shop/cuban-cigars/bolivar-cigars/bolivar-belicosos-finos-cigars-box-of-25/"

a = getstock(txt1)

Debug.Print a

a=getstock (txt2)
Debug.Print a
End Sub

Function getstock(url As String) As Boolean
    Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
         html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim ohtml As Object
 
    Set ohtml = html.querySelectorAll(".stock out-of-stock")
 
    If Not ohtml Is Nothing Then
         getstock = True
    End If
 
End Function
```

Will appreciate a guidance as to why it does not work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector for an element with both classes should be:

```
Set ohtml = HTML.querySelectorAll(".stock.out-of-stock")
```

You need to determine the existence of the classes by looking at the length, i.e. `ohtml.length` is `0` if the selector does not exist.

```
Set ohtml = HTML.querySelectorAll(".stock.out-of-stock")
getstock = ohtml.Length = 0
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tested this but ohtml.length is 0 for bot txt1 and txt2 and txt1  is definitely out of stock. can you please kindly explain why has (".stock out-of-stock") changed to (".stock.out-of-stock") in your suggestion below?

Comment: Actually, it worked - thank you very much. Still would be helpful to understand why space is replaced with ".". Thank you very much again.

Comment: Take a look @ [CSS Selector that applies to elements with two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes)