# How to get an element from a collection without loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If I have:

```
<div class='week-4 data'></div>
<div class='week-4 data'></div>
<div class='week-4 data'></div>
<div class='week-4 chart'></div>
<div class='week-5 data'></div>
<div class='week-5 data'></div>
<div class='week-5 data'></div>
<div class='week-5 chart'></div>
```

How can I get the `chart` element of a given week? `<div class='week-4 chart'></div>`

I tried:

```
$(".week-4:has(.chart)")

$(".week-4").has(".chart")
```

Comment: This question has already been answered on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640996/can-you-target-an-element-with-css-only-if-2-classes-are-present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: `$('.week-4.chart')`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/NaN7B/

Comment: Here is a fiddle to edit all of the weeks charts: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/NaN7B/1/

Comment: dang! So simple and we (developers) just love to complicate :)

Comment: @balexandre that may be true ^_^