# Can you target an element with CSS when inherited classes are present?

Tags: css, css-selectors

You may have multiple classes on an element separated by a space:

```
<div class="header contaminated">...</div>
```

and you can [target that `div` using `.header.contaminated` selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640996/can-you-target-an-element-with-css-only-if-2-classes-are-present).

That's fine when both classes are directly applied to an element. i want to target an element with CSS that has both styles, but one style comes from the ***parent***:

**Example**

```
<div class="contaminated">
  <div class="header">...</div>
</div>
```

Normally i want to style a `header` as blue:

```
.header { background-color:  #99FFFF; }
```

But if a `div` is `contaminated` then i color the entire background red:

```
.contaminated { background-color: Pink; }
.contaminated.header { background-color: HotPink; }
```

Except i don't think the css selector syntax `.contaminated.header` is valid for "inherited" styles.

> **Note**: The reason i don't think it's valid is because it doesn't work

Is it possible to target an element with CSS if it only contains two classes, and some of the classes are "inherited" ?

[**jsFiddle sandbox**](http://jsfiddle.net/r8Lfa/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basic CSS - separate the class names by a space, that implies/applies the cascade:

```
.contaminated .header { ... }
```

Anything wrong with that?

Cheers

Comment: Ah... [back to basics](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#contextual-selectors). (Notice I'm linking to an ancient spec on purpose.)

Comment: I should inform that the cascade doesn't go from an ancestor to a descendant - it only works on a per-element basis, and what we're talking about here is in fact inheritance, a separate matter altogether.

Comment: @BoltClock Huh? Are you saying my answer is wrong?  If not, what *are* you saying?  Let's not confuse a very basic concept.

Comment: I'm just saying you said "cascade" where you should *probably* have said "inheritance". I dunno. *-shrug-*

Comment: @BoltClock i read that before asking! Now that i read it again i....still can't find my answer in there!

Comment: And good god, if i had just randomly kept mashing i might have stumbled into it. i tried `+`, `#`, `,` before thinking i should *ask* rather than guess. In my defense [the css](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#contextual-selectors) spec doesn't mention being able to use `<space>` to separate classes (only elements).

Comment: If you look at the newer specs you'll see something called a descendant combinator...

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused as to your question, wouldn't this do it?

```
.contaminated .header { background-color: HotPink; }
```

Notice the space, saying "look for an element with a class of .header within an element with a class of .contaminated"

Answer (score 1):

```
.contaminated>.header{}
```

will only target element header that are direct children of .contaminated