# Apply CSS Rules Only If 2 Classes are Set to an Element

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you target an element with CSS only if 2 classes are present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640996/can-you-target-an-element-with-css-only-if-2-classes-are-present)
>   [CSS Selector that applies to elements with two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes)

Is there a way to apply a CSS style to an element only if 2 classes are applied to it?

For example, apply my custom styles to this:

```
<div class="one two">Text</div>
```

But not to these:

```
<div class="one">Text</div>
<div class="two">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure:

```
.one.two { border: 1px red solid }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use in css selector `.one.two`